# Comparar Strings Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Comecei a poucos dias a aprender desenvolvimento android, estou tentando criar um sistema de login simples somente para teste. Só que quando crio um evento para o botão login a comparação da string do EditText não dá certo. Quando clico no botão ele vai para o else.

```
public void exibirMensagem(View view){
edUsuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_Usuario);
    if(edUsuario.getText().equals("marcio")){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuário: " + edUsuario.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuário inválido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

tenta colocar assim:

```
edUsuario.getText().toString().equals("") ..
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo.

Comment: haha, valeu amigo!

Comment: Valeu, obrigado!